# How do I write/read to the beginning of a text file?

Tags: java, file, text

**EDIT**
This is my file reader, can I make this read it from bottom to up seeing how difficult it is to make it write from bottom to up.

```
        BufferedReader mainChat = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./messages/messages.txt"));
    String str;
    while ((str = mainChat.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    mainChat.close();
```

**OR (old question)**

How can I make it put the next String at the beginning of the file and then insert an new line(to shift the other lines down)?

```
FileWriter chatBuffer = new FileWriter("./messages/messages.txt",true);
BufferedWriter mainChat = new BufferedWriter(chatBuffer);
mainChat.write(message);
mainChat.newLine();
mainChat.flush();
mainChat.close();
```

Comment: can you just read the file upside down?

Comment: do you know how I can go about making it read from bottom to up?

Comment: the standard java api cannot read file in reverse. it's possible to write a code to read lines starting from the end of file but it will not be easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone could correct me, but I'm pretty sure in most operating systems, there is no option but to read the whole file in, then write it back again.

I suppose the main reason is that, in most modern OSs, all files on the disc start at the beginning of a boundary. The problem is, you cannot tell the file allocation table that your file starts earlier than that point.

Therefore, all the later bytes in the file have to be rewritten. I don't know of any OS routines that do this in one step.

So, I would use a `BufferedReader` to store whole file into a `Vector` or `StringBuffer`, then write it all back with the prepended string first.

--

### Edit

A way that would save memory for larger files, reading @Saury's `randomaccessfile` suggestion, would be:

```
file has N bytes to start with
we want to add on "hello world"
open the file for append
append 11 spaces
i=N
loop {
   go back to byte i
   read a byte 
   move to byte i+11
   write that byte back
   i--
} until i==0
then move to byte 0
write "hello world"
```

voila

Comment: really? is that the only way to go? It seems like such a simple task :(

Comment: I believe so. It is related to how the file system works so i don't think you have an option. It's probably the same for all OS and programming languages unless if there is a trick (but probably not for Java).

Comment: @Cody: It's the physical reality of how hard drives work that limit this. In other words, you're stuck.

Comment: How about reading the file from bottom to up, is that possible or is it a similar problem?

Comment: do you know how I can go about making it read from bottom to up?

Answer (score 0):

Use RandomAccessFile to read/write the file in reverse order. See following links for more details.

```
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/UseRandomAccessFiletoreverseafile.htm
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html
```

Comment: do you know how I can go about making it read from bottom to up?

Comment: Why the downvote ?  I admit it is not the most verbose answer but it is still a valid (though indirect) answer to the OP's problem.  Reasons for downvote is an important source of learning this site can provide.  Don't be shy, put your keyboard where your mouse is...err.. som'tin like that

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from Apache Common IO to simplify this if you can. However, it still needs to read the whole file in so it will be slow for large files.

```
 List<String> newList = Arrays.asList("3");
 File file = new File("./messages/messages.txt");
 newList.addAll(FileUtils.readLines(file));
 FileUtils.writeLines(file, newList);
```

FileUtils also have read/write methods that take care of encoding.

Comment: do you know how I can go about making it read from bottom to up?

Comment: just answered that. check comment above.

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested here pre-pending to a file is rather difficult and is indeed linked to how files are stored on the hard drive.  The operation is not naturally available from the OS so you will have to make it yourself and most obvious answers to this involve reading the whole file and writing it again.  this may be fine for you but will incur important costs and could be a bottleneck for your application performance.

Appending would be the natural choice but this would, as far as I understand, make reading the file unnatural.

There are many ways you could tackle this depending on the specificities of your situation.

If writing this file is not time critical in your application and the file does not grow too big you could bite the bullet and read the whole file, prepend the information and write it again.  apache's [common-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/)'s FileUtils will be of help here simpifying the operation where you can [read the file as a list of strings](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29), prepend the new lines to the list and [write the list again](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeLines%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection%29).

If writing is time critical but have control over the reading or the file.  That is, if the file is to be read by another of your programs.  you could load the file in a list of lines and reverse the list.  Again FileUtils from the common-io library and helper functions in the [Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) class in the standard JDK should do the trick nicely.

If writing is time critical but the file is intended to be read through a normal text editor you could create a small class or program that would read the file and write it in another file with the preferred order.

Comment: I will just make it use a mysql database instead of text file, that should be easier to manage right

Comment: yes, writing to database will alleviate this limitation but it will make a tad more complex to read the information afterwards.  It's all about trade-off, there is always a thousand different ways to do things.  Its all about choosing the path of least resistance to get what you want.  Experience lets you integrate more criterion in this decision.

Comment: well its just text, im just curious how to make the program connect to the database with the login details without fear that someone can decompile it and manually connect and do w.e he wants :S

Comment: you can encrypt the data in the database.  Or perhaps take another database, simpler, something like Berkley DB or something similar for your logs and after a while dump them to a file in the desired order.  That way you protect access to the main database while still having the convenience of a database to write your logs.

Comment: It's not about the contents of the database, the database stores encrypted anonymous messages which get deleted shortly after, the problem is that if they have such access they can then modify database settings, change the password, and other stuff like that which will disable the program.

Comment: hence the interest in a small embedded dedicated database for that.  the rest of the application (if it uses a database) can use a "normal" database elsewhere for the rest of the data.  Since it is the only thing the database is used for you can easily hard-code the database connection details in the application itself.  If your application also provides a dump to text file to get the proper ordering then your database is completely transparent if only for the fact that it incurs a delay for the logs to come out.